# Error 403 Forbidden when configure lifecycle for s3 bucket with boto and python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, lifecycle

I'm programmatically creating and setting up an s3 buckets with boto.

I can create buckets, objects .. and write on objects ...

I would like to configure a lifecycle for bucket but when I run the code below I get this exception:

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden with code SignatureDoesNotMatch.

```
lifecycle = Lifecycle()

lifecycle.add_rule(
    'rulename',
     prefix='/',
     status='Enabled',
     expiration=Expiration(days=1)
)

bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

this debug result can help to answer.

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'

header: x-amz-request-id: tx000000000000000000027-0059db8d59-39289-default

header: Content-Length: 196

header: Accept-Ranges: bytes

header: Content-Type: application/xml

header: Date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:53:13 GMT

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "pyth.py", line 28, in

```
bucket.configure_lifecycle(lifecycle)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 1366, in

configure_lifecycle

```
response.status, response.reason, body)
```

boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

`SignatureDoesNotMatch`

tx000000000000000000027-0059db8d59-39289-default

39289-default-default

```
bucket.configure_lifecycle(lifecycle)
```

Comment: It is unlikely that `prefix='/'` is what you want.  The design of S3 is such that tbe prefix of all objects is empty string `''`, not `'/'` and object keys do not actually start with `/`.  It seems odd that this would throw a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error, but it also appears that you are making a request that would not do what you want, even if it succeeded.

Comment: thanks for your response but i test it with non '/' prefix and it does not work, i want just  to append a  lifecycle configuration then i will making it do what i want. i test the same code with amason s3 bucket and it works

Answer (score 0):

After some research  i can say that this error is caused by the actual ceph version (10.2.7 Jowel) that not support lifecycle policies

$ ceph --version

ceph version 10.2.7-27.el7cp (e0d2d4f2fac9d95a26486121257255260bbec8d5)